# I just tried to use the onActivitiResult of other activities

Tags: android

Google Login connect Error

Android Code..

```
 public class GooglePlusPlugin implements ConnectionCallbacks,
 OnConnectionFailedListener{
 Activity resultactivity;
 private Activity activity;// activity is Unity3D currentActivity
 public void init(String objName, String CallbackName) {

    callbackName = CallbackName;
    unityObjectName = objName;
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity, this, this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).build();

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            resultactivity = new ResultActivity();
            mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
        }
    });
}
 @Override
 public void onConnectionFailed(final ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(resultactivity,
                result.getErrorCode());
                return;
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

startResolutionForResult a call to onActivityResult

I try to use onActivityResult other activities, because not extends the activity in GooglePlusPlugin

```
public class ResultActivity extends FragmentActivity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR
            && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        GooglePlusPlugin.getInstance().reconnect(requestCode, resultCode);
        finish();
    }
}
```

but failed...

error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResultInner(Activity.java:3560)
at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:3536)
at android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(Activity.java:3503)
at com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(Unknown Source)
at kr.co.crooz.plugin.googleplus.GooglePlusPlugin.onConnectionFailed(GooglePlusPlugin.java:212)
```

Why startIntentSenderForResult need, I do not know how to use it.
How to solve?

Thanks for reading long code

private Activity activity; Activity has already been taken from another part.

I like long content. The part that is not.

```
 try {
        this.unityPlayerClass = Class
                .forName("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        this.unityPlayerActivityField = this.unityPlayerClass
                .getField("currentActivity");
        this.unitySendMessageMethod = this.unityPlayerClass.getMethod(
                "UnitySendMessage", new Class[] { String.class,
                        String.class, String.class });

        this.activity = getActivity();
    }

private Activity getActivity() {
    if (this.unityPlayerActivityField != null) {
        try {
            Activity activity = (Activity) this.unityPlayerActivityField
                    .get(this.unityPlayerClass);
            if (activity == null) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Something has gone terribly wrong. The Unity Activity does not exist. This could be due to a low memory situation");
            }
            return activity;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error getting currentActivity: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return this.activity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your Activity is null

```
private Activity activity;// activity is Unity3D currentActivity
```

you declare it here but you never grab the activity from unity3D as i guess you trying to do, this will result that you activity is null and will throw nullpointerexeption

Comment: Sorry to confuse and already in the initialization function. Fixed Post.

Comment: Unity Player Activity get part was added.